# ACE library and files system

Tags: ace

How can I manage files and directories with ACE library? I tried to delete files with ACE_OS::unlink, but it didn't work. I also failed to create directories by using ACE_OS::mkdir. I need to find a way to create and delete directories, delete files and move files from one directory to another

Answer (score 1):

See `ACE_wrappers/tests/OS_Test.cpp` for code how to create, move, and delete files. Use `ACE_OS::mkdir/rmdir` to create/remove directories. See `ACE_wrappers/tests/Dirent_Test.cpp` for code how to retrieve the content of a directory

Comment: Does `ACE_OS::mkdir/rmdir` are platform independent?